# Cannot lock ref error when pulling master branch in Sourcetree

Tags: git, repository, atlassian-sourcetree, branching-and-merging

I returned to a project I haven't worked on in many months and did the following in Sourcetree:

1. Checkout master
2. Pull

But I got this (unable to update local ref) error and can't find a solution:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks fetch --no-tags origin
From https://repository.oursite.com/scm/st_aem/business
 * [new branch]          Feature/AEM-484  -> origin/Feature/AEM-484
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/uat': is at 31a31142607b311f6416fd3765a56e14da0adc8d but expected fadb7c021d646509ed19fbf49802869ffc1d237b

 ! fada7c021...a4375c7f2 release/uat -> origin/release/uat  (unable to update local ref)
Completed with errors, see above.
```

How can I update my master branch without having to worry about old branches that were long ago completed?